# Replace item or update it from Arraylist in a for in loop in node.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

Let's say I have an array of objects, something like:

`{'field1':value1, 'fiedl2':value2, 'field3':value3}`
....

`{'field1':value4, 'fiedl2':value6, 'field3':value1}`

I want each object of the array to be changed, so

```
for(let item of items){
   //update item so it does not contain the old values but new calculated ones, so
   item.fieldA=item.field1+item.field2;
   item.fieldB=item.field3
}
```

So in the end, my array should have objects like:

```
{'fieldA':valueA, 'fieldB':valueB}
```

I am using node and I am trying to see how I can simply update or replace each object with its updated version with new properties and values

Comment: Youre just missing an *delete item.field1* and youre done...

Comment: what is `item.value1`, did you mean `item.field1`?  Where is your array of objects, I just see an object?

Comment: @James indeed, you are right, I edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be worth considering to simply create a new array:

```
items=items.map(before=>({
 fieldA:before.value1+before.value2,
 fieldB:before.value3
}));
```

Or pre ES6:

```
items=items.map(function(before){
 return {
    fieldA:before.value1+before.value2,
     fieldB:before.value3
 };
 }));
```

Through that, the original items are garbagge collected ( may be easier then *delete*ing all unused properties), and the syntax is quite nice.

And its may useful to use object destructuring:

```
items=items.map(
  ({value,value2,unused,...rest})
  =>
  ({result:value+value2,...rest})
);
```

The upper code deletes *unused* and replaces *value* and *value2* with their addition stored as result, all the other parameters are copied too.

Comment: @alin youre missing a *return { ... }* . If the brackets inside the arrow functions are enclosed by (), they arent a block statement anymore but rather an object literal.

Comment: Thank you very much I am new to js and missed it. Indeed now it works!

Comment: @alin youre welcome ;) i admit that its quite confusing.

Comment: I like to use the pre ES6 for functions because I am familiar with java and this makes the move back and forth more easy. Probably I'll have to get into the `=>` one day.

Comment: @alin java is focused on readability and js on *putting some stuff together very fast* , i usually prefer the old function syntax if others need to read it ;)